# it seems we'll get the paper over the line

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

My supervisor wrote an email:

''We've got feedback on how our journal paper went. It seems quite helpful feedback, in that it seems we'll get the paper over the line.''

Could anyone tell me what he meant by '' in that it seems we'll get the paper over the line?''

Thanks

Comment: When you cross the finish line in a race, you win. In this context, over the line means success.

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssss

Comment: The *line* in this case being the success of having it published.

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssss